# Spring Cloud SFTP Sink

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-integration-sftp

Trying to explore Spring cloud solution as starters, for our use case and didn't find any good complete example so reaching out for help. Looking for a Spring Cloud Stream SFTP solution (Sink) to  SFTP a byte stream from DB and this would be cron scheduled on CF. Fallback option is to use Spring Integration SFTP solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an SFTP sink example here:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/master/applications/sink/sftp-sink

Comment: Thanks Gary! Had seen this but I didn't find any source code (under stream-applications-master\applications\sink\sftp-sink\src\). Can you help if I am missing anything here?

Comment: See the POM - it uses the [sftp-consumer function](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/master/functions/consumer/sftp-consumer/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/fn/consumer/sftp).